# Want top frequent words in english

Tags: java, parsing, text, wikipedia

I want most frequent words in english. Basically, I am processing wikipedia text and am stuck with lot of words even after removing stop words. I tried googling for frequent words, but got the below link.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Frequency_lists#English

I have to manually scrape the data from these link. Is there a known source for these words that can be directly downloaded?

Thank you

Comment: Related posts / possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213607/how-to-get-english-language-word-database, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824422/can-i-get-an-english-dictionary-word-list-somewhere, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594098/where-to-get-a-list-of-almost-all-the-words-in-english-language

Comment: Do you understand the question?

Comment: Have you checked that none of the websites referred to in the linked threads contain the data you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in all statistics your answer will depend on what you are sampling. Is your definition of "English" - language used in Wikipedia. As the page you have linked suggests the frequency of words differs based on different samples. Doing a Literature review on language processing work may give you a dated list.

And trust someone to make a website with the that name - [wordfrequency](http://www.wordfrequency.info/). More specifically [this](http://www.wordfrequency.info/files/wordlist_60k.xls).

Comment: The free list is a sample and includes only every 10th word. You'll probably have to buy the complete list...